# JQuery UI droppable accept condition not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

After searching google and stackoverflow for nearly two hours, I just can't get to the bottom of this. I can't find the problem in my code:

HTML:

```
<ul style="list-style:none;cursor:default;">
    <li>uuu</li>
    <li>aaa</li>
</ul>

<div id="canvas" style="height:300px;width:400px;border: 1px solid black"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("li").draggable({
    helper: function () {
       return $("<div class='helper'>test</div>");
    }
});


$("#canvas").droppable({
    accept: ".helper",
    drop: function (ev, ui) {
        var h = ui.helper.clone(false) //$(ui.helper).clone(false) shows the same behaviour
               .removeClass('ui-draggable-dragging')
               .css({position:'relative', left:0, top:0});
        $(this).append(h);
    }
});


$("body").disableSelection();
```

Whatever I do, whenever I specify the "accept" option of .droppable, $("#canvas") won't receive any elements anymore.
Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/98tdy/
Can anyone please tell me the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working becuase you've specified `<div id="#canvas"`

so `$("#canvas")` won't work. simply change the id to `canvas`

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/98tdy/2/)

Comment: The # was a typo on my part when setting the fiddle and copy-pasting it afterwards. The part that I had wrongly understood was the "accept" part. I thought "accept" referred to the helper element that I was cloning, that's why I had put ".helper" there. Now I understand that it refers to the original element that is being dragged, in this case the <li> element. Thank you for making it clear.